# AAPT: error: attribute android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am migrating an app to API level 30 and trying to follow the guidelines from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#migrate-legacy-storage). It says:

> **If your app targets Android 11**
>
> Set the `preserveLegacyExternalStorage` flag to true to preserve the
> legacy storage model so that your app can migrate a user's data when
> they upgrade to the new version of your app that targets Android 11.

As advised, I am setting the flag in respective build flavor's manifest file and there are no warnings or errors inside the code editor. However, problems occur when I try to build the app. I am receiving the following error:

> AndroidManifest.xml:25: AAPT: error: attribute
> android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage not found.

`AndroidManifest.xml` is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The relevant parts from `build.gradle` file are the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 41
        versionName "5.3.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "payments", "API"
    productFlavors {
        google {
            dimension "payments"
        }
        cc {
            dimension "payments"
        }
        defaultAPI {
            minSdkVersion 30
            targetSdkVersion 30
            dimension "API"
        }
        maxAPI29 {
            dimension "API"
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionNameSuffix "-maxAPI29"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

That is, build tools and compile SDK version are set to 30. What else I might be missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that ? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @Gargantua I didn't use the flag at all and (at least in my case) the app was able to import data even without it.